# Load files in view.yml Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm working on a Symfony project and I am seeing this in a view.yml file.  What is the meaning of it:

```
javascript: 
  - js/jquery.min.js
```

I can see that this sentence loads the library but, what the difference between that and this:

```
javascript: [js/jquery.min.js]
```

Also, I have other problem:  When I want load another component, it does not load the jquery library; why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way to do lists in YAML, for example in an app I have:

```
profileViewSuccess:
  javascripts:
    - /jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js
    - /js/jquery.periodicalupdater.js
    - /js/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js
    - /js/jquery-uniform/jquery.uniform.js
    - /js/lightbox.js
    - /js/profile.view.js
    - http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

This looks nicer than:

```
profileViewSuccess:
  javascripts: [/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js, /js/jquery.periodicalupdater.js, /js/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js]
```

etc. etc. with all the other files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you cleared cache running "symfony cc"? When you change a configuration file you must run such command to apply the changes.

Hope this helps. On the other hand your english is pretty hard to understand XD I'm spanish as well but I think spanish is not allowed here.

Comment: thanks! it  work for me. I can find the problem. In my code i had been calling   javascripts files in diferents components and helper, for it , the javascripts code not worked correctly. LuisClemente, my spanish its better that my english :)